# Unnumbering corollaries

Tags: numbering, packages, overleaf, amsthm, mathtools

I would like to number the corollary of the theorem “theorem 1.2.3.” such as “corollary 1.2.3.” Instead of “corollary 1.2.3.1.”. How can I do? I’m using amsthm package.

Comment: What if you have two corollaries to the same theorem?

Comment: I want them to share the same number

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion your readers won't understand. But you're the judge.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem*{corollary}{Corollary \thetheorem}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\section{One}

\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{corollary}
This is the first corollary.
\end{corollary}

\begin{corollary}
This is the second corollary.
\end{corollary}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course corollaries must follow the theorem they refer to without any other theorem in between. Text is allowed, though.